aptitude/dpkg fatal error
cant download anything or use anything that involves apt
trying to download something
sudo apt install nmap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nmap is already the newest version (7.91+dfsg1+really7.80+dfsg1-2ubuntu0.1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  app-install-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 725 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up aptitude (0.8.13-3ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/aptitude corrupt: invalid
 status
dpkg: error processing package aptitude (--configure):
 installed aptitude package post-installation script subprocess returned error e
xit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 aptitude
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


This question is similar to: update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim corrupt: invalid status. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just fixed it by using these commands
Step 1: Open the terminal and use the syntax below to list all the files you need to remove:
sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i [package_name]

Step 2:  Remove the files from the list using the syntax below:
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/[package_name].* /tmp

To complete the process, update the system package repository:
sudo apt update

